# Kubuntu 16.04 ibus does not change language with Alt+Shift

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, ibus, input-method

Because I needed Anthy I enabled ibus and anthy input method on Kubuntu 16.04LTS:
[image: Input Method]
And as seen in screenshot I use the `Alt`+`Shift` in order to change the input method.

I also disabled the layouts provided from the Kubuntu as Well:

[image: Disabled layout]

Also I set ibus as input method as well with the command:

```
im-config -n ibus
```

But I have trouble making the `Alt`+`Shift` change the language with ibus. Can I have some help on that?

Comment: I'm not sure about 16.04, but at least on more recent Kubuntu versions there is no reason to use `ibus-setup` directly. Additional input sources (including IBus input methods) are better handled via the KDE tools. And in that case, if you want to change the shortcut for switching input language, you'd better use KDE's settings to do it.

Comment: But The KDE tools are the ones that  fail to ooffer me the option to  select Anthy as input method in the first place. Also I already used the ibus tools, so howw I can setyp anthy via the KDE ones?

Comment: In 19.10, at least, there is an "Input Method Panel" widget. When you enable that, you can add IBus input methods just as easy as XKB layouts. But, again, I can't tell if that widget is available in 16.04.

Comment: Kubuntu 16.04 is [now end-of-life for support](https://kubuntu.org/news/trusty-14-04-lts-end-of-life-and-end-of-kubuntu-support-for-xenial-16-04-lts/).

Comment: @RikMills The link mentions 14.04 my version is 16.04 hence it is still not EOL as seen in https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas The link DOES mention 16.04. Kubuntu elected to only support 16.04 for 3 years, [as clearly stated in the release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes/Kubuntu#Support_lifespan), not 5. This is normal now for flavours.

Comment: Maybe this [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1576344/290915) answer is useful to someone.